# Redirect requests for default instance to named instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We have moved our database from default instance to named instance of SQL SERVER 2008 R2 (default instance has been uninstalled).

However, we have distributed client software which connect only to default instance of SQL Server over internet on a static IP address.

Any pointers about how to forward connection requests to default instance by clients to the named instance which is hosting the database now?

Thanks and Regards,
Vamyip

Answer (score 1):

Try using database aliases. Run `%windir%\system32\cliconfg.exe` and/or `%windir%\syswow64\cliconfg.exe` and create an alias that points into the new instance. On 32-bit systems, system32 is all you need. On 64 -bit systems, syswow64 is needed if you are running a 32-bit client application.

Next time, do not hard-code database settings. Put connection info into a configuration file.

Comment: I tried to create alias but couldn't find how to address defualt instance while creating alias.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Configuration Manager:

- Ensure the named instance you want to be the default is using the default port of 1433.
- Add an alias named "MSSQLSERVER", protocol TCP/IP, port 1433.